# Newton's Law of Gravitation and dark matter

Tags: newtonian-gravity, black-holes, dark-matter, dark-energy, modified-gravity

Before the days of Einstein the observation that light incident to the Earth's surface appears to be constant no matter whether the transmitter is travelling away from the earth or towards the earth was spuriously explained by the theory that there existed an invisible ether surrounding the earth that sped light waves/photons up or slowed them down accordingly thereby  taking into account the Earths's relative velocity to the source.

It seems to me that the theory that over 80 percent of our galaxy is composed of dark matter (as yet undetected) but deemed necessary hold the galaxy together is simply more of the same sort of guff in the same vein.

Newton's famous equation that determines the force of gravity between 2 masses to be proportionate to the product of those masses divided by distance squared is intuitively correct. However the constant of proportionality $G$ -the so called UNIVERSAL GRAVITATIONAL CONSTANT is somewhat suspect. How do we know it to be truly universal in the context of galactic scales of distance and the super massive singularities such as might occur at the center of our galaxy?

If we take the black hole at the center of our own galaxy Isn't it more likely to be the case that $G$ in this context varies with distance from the center like a damped oscillation with increasingly positive values within our own galaxy but negative values that spread out across the entire observable universe. I'm thinking that maybe such a theory could account for the reason that galaxies hold together and go someway to explaining why the universe is expanding. Eg replacing theories of dark matter as well as dark energy of which real evidence is so very sparse.
I'm guessing somewhere somebody has tried to model this. What were the results?

Comment: It seems likely that you are interested on MOND models. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Newtonian_dynamics

Comment: "It seems to me ... sort of guff" You should consider how you arrived at this opinion. The evidence here has a lot of different strands; I get the impression perhaps you have not studied most of these strands of evidence. Also, the idea of bringing in a modification to Newtonian gravity has occurred to a lot of people before you; it too has been studied in depth.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is nothing intuitive about Newton's Law of Gravity.  No one on Earth had a clue that the same 'force' that caused an apple to fall to the Earth was the same 'force' that was holding the moon.  This was an enormous leap away from intuition.

Second, sure, maybe the gravitational constant isn't constant.  What you need to do is what Newton did: reduce your idea into a formula that can be tested.  Then you try it out on every observation you can get your hands on.  When you've done that, if the formula still works, come back here and tell us what it is and you may find a curious soul who's willing to test it out.

What you'll likely find is that Newton's theory (incorporated into General Relativity) is still the best model in that it accounts for the most observations.  You're not the first person to have this idea.  Modifying the law of gravity works well on LSB and small spiral galaxies (in fact, better than Newton!).  It hasn't worked well to explain galaxy cluster dynamics, describe the Cosmic Microwave Background power spectrum or predict the brightness of SNe Ia supernovae.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems to me that the theory that over 80 percent of our galaxy is composed of dark matter (as yet undetected) but deemed necessary hold the galaxy together is simply more of the same sort of guff in the same vein.

Aether was one hypothesis introduced to explain one observation.

Dark matter is one hypothesis introduced to explain almost a dozen independent observations with zillions of data points, from cosmology and astrophysics, spanning from the Cosmic Microwave Background and Structure Formation to galaxy clusters (merging or not), gravitational lenses, and yes, rotation curves of galaxies. Sure, dark matter might still turn out to be a red herring, in science how can one ever be "sure". But as far as Occam's razor is concerned, dark matter is as good a hypothesis as there ever will be.

Answer (score 0):

Dark matter is not distributed evenly across the universe so I don't think we could consider it coming from the centre black hole of galaxies.  Physicists have used gravitational lensing to map it very clearly and it is very closely associated with particular galaxies.  For example, they used gravitational lensing around the bullet cluster of galaxies as one of the earliest strong evidence that dark matter exists.  Here are four images from that study.  The dark matter is in blue and the normal matter is in pink:  [image: Bullet Cluster]

More recent studies have shown that slow moving galaxies have less dark matter, and that more diffuse galaxies have less dark matter.  For example, a recent study* found “a clear connection between the distribution of stars within massive galaxies and halo mass….  At fixed total stellar mass, massive galaxies with more extended mass distributions tend to live in more massive dark matter haloes."

This has given rise to my own speculative theory [found here](https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D7718709_68878570_6313519) that dark matter is not matter at all, but rather is just gravity, caused by the fast moving galaxy generating a bow wave and subsequent excitation of the gluon field interacting with the particulate space of loop quantum gravity.

There is very strong direct photographic evidence that dark matter exists and that it is localized around particular galaxies.  The only question to answer is what is it made of.

*Royal Astronomical Society, Monthly Notices, December 5, 2019.  Weak lending reveals a tight connection between dark matter halo mass and the distribution of stellar mass in massive galaxies.